# Migrate multiple source data rows in Drupal

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7, migration, drupal-commerce

Has anyone tried migrating fields with multiple source data rows? In my case, Im migrating values of commerce file field (https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_file).
It only migrated 1 id where it should have multiple id's.
I've checked the query in the source database, it outputs correctly, my problem is upon migration.

Here's what I did.

```
    $query->addExpression('GROUP_CONCAT(file.field_file_fid)', 'file_id');
    .
    .
    .
    .
    $this->addFieldMapping('commerce_file', 'file_id')
            ->sourceMigration('PrivateFile')
            ->separator(',');
    $this->addFieldMapping('commerce_file:file_class')
            ->defaultValue('MigrateFileFid');
    $this->addFieldMapping('commerce_file:preserve_files')
            ->defaultValue(1);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: are you using only migration module ?

Comment: it isn't enough just to map the field, you have to write also the prepareRow() function

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ArditMeti. Im using group concat function in my query, it would give a comma separated value. For this to be read by field mappings, I added separator(',') with it. https://www.drupal.org/node/1012810.
I tried this without using sourceMigration and it works but it just uses the file ids from the source database. I've also read yesterday that sourceMigration doesn't support multiple data source rows.
So I think, my last resort would be to create a query in my prepareRow() that works like the sourceMigration().

Comment: I can't help you much, I just migrated a wordpress database (as xml) in drupal. I had to extend an already made class (which was extending Migration class). It had already prepared the source and destination so I had to do only the field mappings and to add those xml fields to the $row variable in the prepareRow()